# XSLT: extract set of elements from XML file and get the values from txt file

Tags: xml, xslt, text

I have two files: Rules_Generic File (generic.xml) & (Rules_Values.txt). 
I want to find a way to write a new XML file by extract the Rules syntax from generic.xml and fill the values from Rules_Values.txt

I searched and found that XSLT could be used. the following is (Rules_Values.txt)

```
#VNF_Type   VNF_Id    min_num_Instance  max_num_Instance    ScalingOut%     ScalingIn%      min_num_CPUs        max_num_CPUs    Migration_Type  

Firewall     f1             1                   4                   60%            20%              4               8               Pre-Copy
Firewall     f2             2                   6                   80%            10%              2               6               Post-Copy   
Cache        c1             2                   8                   90%            30%              2               6               Hybrid
```

the following is (generic.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PolicySet  PolicySetId="PS2" PolicySetName="ResourceAdaptation" Client_Id =" ">
    <PolicySet SFC_Name="">
        <Policy PolicyId=" ">
            <Target>
                <Subject>VNF_Type</Subject>     
            </Target>
    <!-- Horizontal_Scaling -->         
            <Rule RuleId="R1" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>VNF_ID</Subject>
                    <Action>Horizontal_Scaling</Action>             
                    <Resource>numOfInstances</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>min_numOfInstances: Any_Positive_Integer</condition>
                <condition>max_numOfInstances: Any_Positive_Integer</condition>     
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
    <!-- Vertical_Scaling -->   
            <Rule RuleId="R2" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>VNF_ID</Subject>
                    <Action>Vertical_Scaling</Action>               
                    <Resource>numOfCPUcores</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>min_numOfCPUcores: Any_Positive_Integer</condition>
                <condition>max_numOfCPUcores: Any_Positive_Integer</condition>  
            </conditions>           
            </Rule> 
    <!-- Horizontal-Scaling threshold-based 1- scaling_Out 2- scaling_In -->        
            <Rule RuleId = "R3" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>VNF_ID</Subject>               
                    <Action>Scaling_Out</Action>                
                    <Resource>cpu_Utilization</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>utilization greater_than threshold%</condition>                      
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId = "R4" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>VNF_ID</Subject>                               
                    <Action>Scaling_In</Action>             
                    <Resource>cpu_Utilization</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>utilization less_than threshold%</condition>                     
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
    <!-- For Migration : specify 1. MigrationType 2.  -->           
            <Rule RuleId = "R7" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>VNF_ID</Subject>                                                       
                    <Action>Migration</Action>              
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>MigrationType: [Pre-Copy , Post-Copy, Hybrid]</condition>
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>

        </Policy>   
    </PolicySet>


</PolicySet>
```

AND the desired output (out.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PolicySet  PolicySetId="PS2" PolicySetName="ResourceAdaptation" Client_Id =" ">
    <PolicySet SFC_Name="">
        <Policy PolicyId="p1">
            <Target>
                <Subject>Firewall</Subject>     
            </Target>
            <Rule RuleId="R1" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f1</Subject>
                    <Action>Horizontal_Scaling</Action>             
                    <Resource>numOfInstances</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>min_numOfInstances: 1</condition>
                <condition>max_numOfInstances: 4</condition>    
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId="R2" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f1</Subject>
                    <Action>Vertical_Scaling</Action>               
                    <Resource>numOfCPUcores</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>min_numOfCPUcores: 4</condition>
                <condition>max_numOfCPUcores: 8</condition>     
            </conditions>           
            </Rule> 
            <Rule RuleId = "R3" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f1</Subject>               
                    <Action>Scaling_Out</Action>                
                    <Resource>cpu_Utilization</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>utilization greater_than 60%</condition>                     
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId = "R4" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f1</Subject>                               
                    <Action>Scaling_In</Action>             
                    <Resource>cpu_Utilization</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>utilization less_than 20%</condition>                        
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId = "R5" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f1</Subject>                                                       
                    <Action>Migration</Action>              
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>MigrationType: Pre-Copy</condition>
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId="R6" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f2</Subject>
                    <Action>Horizontal_Scaling</Action>             
                    <Resource>numOfInstances</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>min_numOfInstances: 2</condition>
                <condition>max_numOfInstances: 6</condition>    
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId="R7" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f2</Subject>
                    <Action>Vertical_Scaling</Action>               
                    <Resource>numOfCPUcores</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>min_numOfCPUcores: 2</condition>
                <condition>max_numOfCPUcores: 6</condition>     
            </conditions>           
            </Rule> 
            <Rule RuleId = "R8" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f2</Subject>               
                    <Action>Scaling_Out</Action>                
                    <Resource>cpu_Utilization</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>utilization greater_than 80%</condition>                     
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId = "R9" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f2</Subject>                               
                    <Action>Scaling_In</Action>             
                    <Resource>cpu_Utilization</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>utilization less_than 10%</condition>                        
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId = "R10" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f1</Subject>                                                       
                    <Action>Migration</Action>              
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>MigrationType: Post-Copy</condition>
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>                                 
        </Policy>
        <Policy PolicyId="p2">
            <Target>
                <Subject>Cache</Subject>        
            </Target>
            <Rule RuleId="R11" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>c1</Subject>
                    <Action>Horizontal_Scaling</Action>             
                    <Resource>numOfInstances</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>min_numOfInstances: 2</condition>
                <condition>max_numOfInstances: 8</condition>    
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId="R12" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>c1</Subject>
                    <Action>Vertical_Scaling</Action>               
                    <Resource>numOfCPUcores</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>min_numOfCPUcores: 2</condition>
                <condition>max_numOfCPUcores: 6</condition>     
            </conditions>           
            </Rule> 
            <Rule RuleId = "R13" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>c1</Subject>               
                    <Action>Scaling_Out</Action>                
                    <Resource>cpu_Utilization</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>utilization greater_than 90%</condition>                     
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId = "R14" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>c1</Subject>                               
                    <Action>Scaling_In</Action>             
                    <Resource>cpu_Utilization</Resource>
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>utilization less_than 30%</condition>                        
            </conditions>           
            </Rule>
            <Rule RuleId = "R15" Effect="Affinity">
                <Target>
                    <Subject>f1</Subject>                                                       
                    <Action>Migration</Action>              
                </Target>
            <conditions>
                <condition>MigrationType: Hybrid</condition>
            </conditions>           
            </Rule> 
        </Policy>           
    </PolicySet>


</PolicySet>
```

My code as the following (.java):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SaxonApiException {

        Processor proc = new Processor(false);
        XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();
        XsltExecutable exp = comp.compile(new StreamSource(new File(
                "C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/PolicyFiles_Generator_V2/src/transformation.xsl")));
        Serializer out = proc.newSerializer();
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
        out.setOutputFile(new File("output.xml"));
        XsltTransformer trans = exp.load();
        trans.setInitialTemplate(new QName("main"));
        trans.setDestination(out);
        trans.transform();
}
```

.xsl code is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vText" select="tokenize(unparsed-text('file:///C:/Users/eclipse-workspace/PolicyFiles_Generator_V2/src/Rules_Values.txt'),'&#xa;')"/>

  <xsl:template  match="/">
    <shirts>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('C:/Users/Hsuwi/eclipse-workspace/PolicyFiles_Generator_V2/src/GenericTemplate.xml')"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </shirts>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="main" match="/">
        <items>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vText">
                <item>
                   ...........
            </xsl:for-each>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know how to complete the xsl code in order to extract the Rule from the 1st xml file and fill each Rule with values from .txt file

Any advice ? help ?? or if there any other way to acheive the objective. 
.txt file is flexible (which mean I can re-order the elements)

Comment: You might want to simplify the input data and result data a bit to explain what you need, does every line in that `.txt` file generate the same number of rules? I don't understand the relation between the text data and the XML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen As first step,let assume that every line generate the same number of rules. the relation between the input file & out as the following: In each line exist in .txt file will produce set of Rules. col 3+4 give the values for Horizontal scaling rule(ex: R1), col. 5 contain the value of scaling_out (R3). So my main objective is to generate a new xml file contains set of rules with specific values (the syntax of the rules take from generic.xml) and the values from .txt file. If you have any other suggestion for the txt file ??

Comment: Your XML has 7 `Rule` elements, your text sample has three data lines, shouldn't the output have 3 x 7, that is, 21 rules?

Comment: @MartinHonnen actually my xml file has 5 rules,  but the last one is with wrong id (it R5 not R7). So the output file should contain 3 * 5 = 15 Rules

Comment: @MartinHonnen what is the way to extract the Rule syntax from  the xml file and insert the values from the .txt !!

Comment: So far I don't see any clear match between column names in the .txt file and any element name or data in the XML, you have `VNF_Id` in the text but `VNF_Type` in the XML (that might work with case-insensitive matching) but I don't see how to relate `min_num_CPUs` to `min_numOfCPUcores: Any_Positive_Integer` with a simple text matching.

Comment: It looks more like you would be better off to write an XSLT that has a function or template with the input parameters you expect to create a set of five rules populated from the parameters and then you would need to call that function or template for each line in the text file, making sure each column value is passed in as the right parameter.

Comment: @MartinHonnen if we assume that always col. 3+4 values are the values of the first Rule,  (R1), col. 4 for R3, col.5 for R4 col.6+7 for R2 and last col for the last Rule (always like that) and finally col2(vnf_Id ) contain the value of the <subject> for each Rule.so for each line exist in .txt file I have to copy these 5 Rule syntax and change some elements values (new values from .txt)

Answer (score 0):

There is too much and too varied sample data in your question for a precise answer but as said in a comment I wonder whether and approach that defines a named template or function taking the number of values you want to fill as named arguments e.g.

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:fill-template" as="element(Policy)">
      <xsl:param name="p1"/>
      <xsl:param name="p2"/>
      <xsl:param name="p3"/>
      <Policy xsl:expand-text="yes">
          <Rule>
              <foo>test {$p2}</foo>
          </Rule>
          <Rule att="{$p1}">
              ...
          </Rule>
          <Rule>
              <header>...</header>
              <value>... {$p3}</value>
          </Rule>
      </Policy>
  </xsl:function>
```

and then calls that function for each line in your text as needed e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">


  <xsl:function name="mf:fill-template" as="element(Policy)">
      <xsl:param name="p1"/>
      <xsl:param name="p2"/>
      <xsl:param name="p3"/>
      <Policy xsl:expand-text="yes">
          <Rule>
              <foo>test {$p2}</foo>
          </Rule>
          <Rule att="{$p1}">
              ...
          </Rule>
          <Rule>
              <header>...</header>
              <value>... {$p3}</value>
          </Rule>
      </Policy>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:param name="data" as="xs:string">P1  P2  P3
a b c
c d f
g h i</xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <PolicySet>
        <xsl:for-each select="tail(tokenize($data, '\r?\n'))">
            <xsl:sequence select="let $args := tokenize(., '\s+') return mf:fill-template($args[1], $args[2], $args[3])"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </PolicySet>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The example, for completeness and compactness uses a string parameter but you could of course use `<xsl:param name="data" select="unparsed-text('file.txt')"/>` instead.

Online sample is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CH.

Not sure whether that helps but stuffing that suggestion into a comment would be rather difficult.

I realize I have not processed your input XML but rather assumed you are able to adapt it and construct a function with a template/sequence constructor of it. It might be possible to automate that but currently I don't see how to match the various column names to different and variable in text positions in the XML sample.